# Return owner of process given PID

Tags: ubuntu, grep, terminal, process

I'm trying to grab the owner of a process from a list.

I have the command `pidof nmap` to get the  then `ps -u <PID> | grep USER` that I'm currently playing around with. But when I run it, it ends up just printing the titles (top line):

[image: screenshot of ps]

How can I grab the name of the owner given the process ID?

Comment: `ps -u <PID>` actually selects processes by effective user id, not PID.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html

Comment: See also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/479746/how-to-find-pids-user-name-in-linux/1024197) on how to get the owner of a process in Linux.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
ps -o user= -p PIDHERE
```

This selects the process `PIDHERE` with `-p`, then instructs `ps` to format the output by printing only the column named `user`; the `=` sign means "rename the column `user` to (nothing)", effectively removing the header line.

Comment: So is that (nothing), nothing, "nothing", "", , '', or just what?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 it's hard to denote "nothing" via text; sorry for the confusion. There's no replacement text after the equals-sign.